# Which color packs overlap?

Tags: draw-something

Looking over the color shop, I can see some color are available in different packs, for example both the **fall package** and the **holiday package** contains the same shade of yellow, which is included in the **shades of yellow** pack as well. If I want to minimize the coins spent and still buy all available colors, which packs should do I choose? which packs are available in separate packs? Can I still buy a color pack even if I have all it's colors from different packs or does it automatically count as "unlocked"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have purchased 2 packs with the coins I have earned, so I can understand what you mean as I have 2 yellow colors overlapping. There are many colors within the packages shown below that you can barely notice any tint difference in play.

*It is completely up to you* in the end which packages you would like and which tints or variations you would like to enjoy the game to its fullest, but my recommendation would be: **Holiday package and the Mardi Gras package.**  Both packages + the original set give you the main set of colors required to illustrate a proper, defined picture.

My reasoning:

Between the Mardi Gras package + the holiday package + original set you gain:

- Red[removes red scale package,  half of fall package, part of neon package]
- Purple [removes spring and neon package]
- (2 different tints of) blue[removes bluescale package, part of spring package, beach package]
- Green [ neon package ]
- Yellow [removes fall package (see brown below), part of spring package]
- brown [removes fall package, ice cream package]
- Different shades of black - gray[removes grayscale package].

The reasoning above accesses every package (besides minor differences in the shade packages).

*Sidenote: I wouldn't bother with the shade packages at all.*

Take a look at the screens I have provided below.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll wait a couple of few days so someone else will have the chance to details exactly which color packs overlap and which are the minimum to get, if not, I'll accept your answer

Comment: @JohnoBoy Anytime.  Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I would get the spring package first since that way you get a green, orange and purple all at once leaving you with access to all primary and secondary colors with just one package... Then the ice cream package so you have a brown and a pink (I had to draw Kirby today without pink...)

Answer (score 1):

Mardi gras and spring are my choices. Mardi gras is the first you need, IMO. Brown, grey, purple, green, orange. All super vital. Spring is good because of the pink. Maybe I'll try holiday too.

Answer (score 0):

I bought the Mardi Gras package first, because you get the most versatile colors that way. While the spring package has some similar colors, they are pastels and not as useful.

The 2nd package I bought was the brazilian desert package. Really helped because I got a light beige color suitable for light skin tones, and and nice sepia good for darker skin tones, plus a couple of pinks (that I used to draw Kirby) and a brown-gray that is pretty versatile.

Third, I bought the beach package which gave me 3 more shades of blue good for sky and water. The sand color i use for wood a lot, but what is striking is the off-white color that at first doesn't appear to be useful, I find I'm using all the time. Just yesterday I used it as the main color for mummy bandages, because the white didn't look realistic.

I got by for a long time with those three packages, so those are the 3 to start with. I've just decided to add a couple of more, just for fun. The spooky pack has a couple of great shades of light green that would add versatility for drawing foliage, but the Holiday package has great colors too.

Answer (score 0):

Just get all the the ones that aren't 'single colour' packages. Seeing as you can't buy much with the colours left over then just invest them into paint. In my opinion they should have red to yellow, green to blue, greyscale and then the beach and ice cream packs combined. I was thinking of the pink and brown and beige from ice cream mixed with the blues from the beach because they are nice... If it is just one shade per colour then you could get away with the Mardi Gras + Spring.