# How to get more colours?

Tags: draw-something

How can I get different brush colours? I am on iPhone and my friend on Android has different colours. This [post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56285/which-color-packs-overlap) mentions that there is a colour shop, but I can only seem to find a bomb shop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you are on the screen drawing there should be a little plus next to your color selection that says something like 'Add Colors' there you can purcahse colors for coins I believe.

Comment: Ahh right there in front of me.... A centralized shop would be nice.

Comment: Yes, the shop is very misleading. And also I don't think you can access the color shop unless it is literaly your turn.